# Retrieve query, form, and report properties from Access (.accdb) via a WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ms-access

Is there a way to get the objects (queries, forms, reports, macros, etc.) from an `.accdb` file? I am not looking for storing data, I want to examine the structure and design of those objects.

Edit: To make the question clear. I want to access those objects from C#, so that I can do automatic checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following C# console app lists all of the controls in a specified Form:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace comAutoTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // this code requires the following COM reference in the project:
            // Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library
            //
            var objAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
            objAccess.Visible = false;
            objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");

            string formName = "MembersForm";
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The form [{0}] contains the following controls:", formName));
            objAccess.DoCmd.OpenForm(formName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcFormView.acDesign);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Form frm = objAccess.Forms[formName];
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Control ctl in frm.Controls)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    [{0}]", ctl.Name));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("        {0}", ctl.GetType()));
            }
            objAccess.DoCmd.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcObjectType.acForm, formName);
            objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase();
            objAccess.Quit();

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
The form [MembersForm] contains the following controls:

    [LastName]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.TextBoxClass

    [Label0]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.LabelClass

    [MemberDonationsSubform]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.SubFormClass

    [MemberDonationsSubform Label]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.LabelClass

    [Command3]
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.CommandButtonClass

Done.
```

Edit: For Relationships, do something like this

```csharp
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Database cdb = objAccess.CurrentDb();
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.Relation rel in cdb.Relations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rel.Name);
}
```

Comment: One more question. When I use `Application.ExportXML`, I made some silly mistake. The database then locked up. I had to reboot every time that happened. Although I now can use `Application.ExportXML` without any problem, I'd like to know where there is a way to unlock the database without reboot. Just in case this happens when I am testing other functions.

Comment: @Martin Did you try going into the Windows Task Manager and killing `MSACCESS.EXE` from the "Processes" tab?

Comment: I did, but I didn't see any MSACCESS.EXE process. I saw MyProgram.vhost.exe (I think that's what it was), but I couldn't kill it. I also tried unlocker. After unlocker unlock the accdb file, I could remove the laccdb. But I still couldn't open the database without reboot.

Comment: I am using my home computer and killing MSACCESS.EXE does the trick. It might be because I am not the admin of that other computer.

I can get the tables, forms, etc. How do I get relationships? I checked the Access Object Model reference, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Again, thanks a bunch! I couldn't seem to find the documentation about this topic. I didn't find anything useful. Can you point me to some documentations or books?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Access that is called "Database Document". You can access it through the Database Tools ribbon panel. When you run the tool fol all objects it will generate a report called Objects Definition. You can print it, but I recommend you export it to a file of some sort (e.g. Excel, or Text). That way it will be easier to analyse.